# ADO Query of ListObject Returning Only NULL Values For Wrong RecordCount

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado, listobject

I have the following procedure meant to query a ListObject via ADO.

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
cnn.Open

Dim tblRange As String
tblRange = quoteWK.ListObjects("quoteWKStateInfo").Range().Address(False, False)

Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT WkStateCd FROM [quoteWK$" & tblRange & "]"

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic
```

However, the recordset is only returning 23 records, when the table has 198. Also, the value for each field is null (`debug.print rs.Fields(0).Value`).

I have searched online quite a bit but cannot see the issue. I have also played with `CursorType` and `LockType`. Below I have placed what I think is important information as well as a picture of the table.

```
?tblRange | Q4:AG206
?strSQL | SELECT WkStateCd FROM [quoteWK$Q4:AG206]
?rs.Fields(0).Value | Null
?rs.RecordCount | 23 
?rs.Fields.Count | 1 'this is correct
```

Also, FWIW, when I run a `SELECT DISTINCT` against the table, I get no records returned. There are 15 distinct states in the WkStateCd column.

[image]

Comment: I've run into some weird issue placing the start of my table somewhere else than A1 with ADO. E.g. inserting rows before the start of the table decrements the `RecordCount`. If you can reorient the table to start on A1, that might help. Alternatively, have you considered using Advanced Filter, or another method to achieve similar results?

Comment: @RyanWildry - Thanks. Yes, I can use advanced filter or another option. My colleague built via ADO since its faster in general, though not without its quirks, as I have also discovered in the past.

Comment: Let us know if moving the table to start in A1 works.

Comment: @RyanWildry - What do you know. That solved it. However, that's a pretty crappy solution, considering that workbook designs can have tables anywhere! If someone can post a more robust and dynamic solution, that would be great.

Comment: Try leaving off the `LockType`. E.g. open the recordset like: `rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic`

Comment: Hi, Did anybody solve the issue? I have the same, recordcount = 5 but i have nulls in Recordset only. So it is empty...